# Is Laravel Request `hasHeader` case-insensitive?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm writing a middleware to change the response based on if a header is present:

```php
class MiddlewareName
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->hasHeader('referer')){
            // Do stuff
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Looking at the source code for the `hasHeader` method in Laravel 8.x, it eventually leads to this method in the `InteractsWithInput` trait:

```php
protected function retrieveItem($source, $key, $default)
{
    if (is_null($key)) {
        return $this->$source->all();
    }

    return $this->$source->get($key, $default);
}
```

I couldn't go further down the source to find out whether headers are converted to lowercase or whether it's normalized somewhere along the line.

Does Laravel convert them to lower-case?

Considering the HTTP standard is case-insensitive on headers, will something like `$request->hasHeader('Content-Type')` still work if the client sends the header as `content-type`?

Comment: Yep, it's gonna work fine. Laravel doesn't do any magic on the headers.

Comment: @Andrei so as I understand, it doesn't really care whether it's `Content-Type` or `cOnTeNt-TyPe`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can write it however you want(case wise) as long as the words are correct.

Comment: Please be aware the referrer header is spelled `Referer` in HTTP (note the missing second r) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Comment: @ontrack Thanks, that was a typo, I edited the spelling to avoid confusing people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP Headers are case-insensitive and Laravel hasHeader() is going along and there is not any strict check here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Laravel request header is case sensitive.

Comment: Could you provide more information? Your answer contradicts what I picked to be correct at that time so I'm wondering if this is a Laravel 9.x change.